# How can I draw my shapes based on their Z order value?

Tags: c#

I'm using C# and I'm drawing shapes to a PictureBox.

I'm not drawing anything in 3D. Instead, I draw 2D shapes and have a "depth" value. (which changes the size of the shape and its opacity)

**My problem is**:

The shapes in the "back" (that are "deep", or basically have high Z value) overlap the shapes in the "front" (the ones with a low Z value).

How can I draw my shapes so that objects with a high Z value overlap the objects with a lower Z value, if they meet.

[image: I want the green ball to render on top of the red ball]

I want the green ball to render on top of the red ball.

**What I tried for this problem**:

Ordering the shapes by their Z value, (descending and ascending) and then drawing them.

Attached here is some code:

My Game.cs: (basically just has a List of Particles)

```
class Game
{
    public List<Particle> Particles;

    public Game()
    {
        Particles = new List<Particle>();
    }
}
```

My Particle.cs:

```
class Particle
{
    //NOTES--------------------------------------------------
    //Z should always be between 0 and 10.
    //When setting the location locally, make sure to use Location
    //because it changes the other properties with it.
    //-------------------------------------------------------
    #region Properties
    public Pen spawnPen;
    //currentPen for when the color is changing
    //and we need to keep the initial color in spawnPen
    public Pen currentPen;

    public Pen borderPen;

    public Brush spawnBrush;
    //currentBrush for when the color is changing
    //and we need to keep the initial color in spawnBrush.
    public Brush currentBrush;

    public bool ColorChanging = false;
    //The center point of the GraphicsPath
    //that we generated in Window.cs, the main file
    //possibly used for calculating the distance
    //to know by how much to change the color??????
    public PointF ColorChangingRegionCenter;

    //2D movement so we don't need a Z axis for speed.
    private PointF speed;
    public PointF Speed
    { get { return speed; } set { speed = value; } }

    private Vector3D location;
    public Vector3D Location
    {
        get { return location; }
        set
        {
            location = value;
            //50 is the width and height of the shapes at depth 0
            //(the maximum width and height, basically).
            rect = new RectangleF(location.X, location.Y, 50.0f - (location.Z * 4), 50.0f - (location.Z * 4));
            if (spawnPen == null)
                spawnPen = new Pen(Color.FromArgb(180 - (int)location.Z * 15, 76, 247, 219));
            if (spawnBrush == null)
                spawnBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(180 - (int)location.Z * 15, 76, 247, 219));
            if (borderPen == null)
                borderPen = new Pen(Color.FromArgb(235, 76, 247, 219), 1);
        }
    }

    private RectangleF rect;
    public RectangleF Rectangle
    { get { return rect; } set { rect = value; } }
    #endregion
    #region Constructors
    //Must explicity set the location
    //otherwise it's random.
    public Particle()
    {
        Random rng = new Random();
        float X, Z;

        //Lock the Random object
        //so it doesn't generate the same value!
        lock (rng)
        {
            X = (float)rng.NextDouble();
        }
        lock (rng)
        {
            Z = (float)rng.NextDouble();
        }
        Location = new Vector3D(X * 1100, 0, Z * 10);
        //We must generate the speed for 2 reason:
        //1.It is not set by default.
        //2.It depends on the Z value of the particle.
        speed = new PointF(2 - (location.Z * 2 / 10), 2 - (location.Z * 2 / 10));
    }
    public Particle(Pen spawnPen) : this()
    { this.spawnPen = spawnPen; }
    public Particle(Brush spawnBrush) : this()
    { this.spawnBrush = spawnBrush; }

    public Particle(float X, float Y, float Z)
    { Location = new Vector3D(X, Y, Z); }
    public Particle(float X, float Y, float Z, Pen spawnPen)
            : this(X, Y, Z)
    { this.spawnPen = spawnPen; }
    public Particle(float X, float Y, float Z, Brush spawnBrush)
            : this(X, Y, Z)
    { this.spawnBrush = spawnBrush; }
    #endregion
    #region Methods
    public void PerformFrame()
    {
        /*//If it is in the ColorChangingRegion
        if (ColorChanging)
        {
            double dLocationColorChangingCenter = Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow((location.X - ColorChangingRegionCenter.X), 2) + Math.Pow(location.Y - ColorChangingRegionCenter.Y, 2));
            if (currentBrush == null)
                currentBrush = spawnBrush;
            Pen brushColor = new Pen(currentBrush);
            //currentBrush = new SolidBrush(brushColor.Color.A + (255 - brushColor.Color.A) * );
            //Remember to dispose of unused objects.
        }*/
        //If traveling UP
        if (speed.Y < 0)
        {
            //If goes offscreen TOP
            if (location.Y < 0 - rect.Height)
            {
                //Send it to offscreen BOTTOM.
                //Location.Y = 500 + rect.Height;
                Location = new Vector3D(location.X, 500 + rect.Height, location.Z);
            }
        }
        //If traveling DOWN
        else if (speed.Y > 0)
        {
            //If goes offscreen BOTTOM
            if (location.Y > 500 + rect.Height)
            {
                //Send it to offscreen TOP.
                //Location.Y = -rect.Height;
                Location = new Vector3D(location.X, -rect.Height, location.Z);
            }
        }
        //If traveling LEFT
        if (speed.X < 0)
        {
            //If goes offscreen LEFT
            if (location.X < 0 - rect.Width)
            {
                //Send it to offscreen RIGHT.
                //Location.X = 1100 + rect.Width;
                Location = new Vector3D(1100 + rect.Width, location.Y, location.Z);
            }
        }
        //If traveling RIGHT
        else if (speed.X > 0)
        {
            //If goes offscreen RIGHT
            if (location.X > 1100 + rect.Width)
            {
                //Send it to offscreen LEFT.
                //Location.X = -rect.Width;
                Location = new Vector3D(-rect.Width, location.Y, location.Z);
            }
        }
        //Change the particle's location.
        //Location.X += speed.X;
        //Location.Y += speed.Y;
        Location = new Vector3D(location.X + speed.X, location.Y + speed.Y, location.Z);
    }
    public void RenderEmptyRectangle(Graphics g)
    {
        g.DrawRectangle(spawnPen, rect.X - rect.Width, rect.Y - rect.Height, rect.Width, rect.Height);
    }
    public void RenderFilledRectangle(Graphics g)
    {
        g.FillRectangle(spawnBrush, rect.X - rect.Width, rect.Y - rect.Height, rect.Width, rect.Height);
    }
    public void RenderEmptyCircle(Graphics g)
    {
        g.DrawEllipse(spawnPen, rect.X - rect.Width, rect.Y - rect.Height, rect.Width, rect.Height);
    }
    public void RenderFilledCircle(Graphics g)
    {
        g.FillEllipse(spawnBrush, rect.X - rect.Width, rect.Y - rect.Height, rect.Width, rect.Height);
    }
    public void RenderCircleBorder(Graphics g)
    {
        g.DrawEllipse(borderPen, rect.X - rect.Width - 1, rect.Y - rect.Height - 1, rect.Width + 1, rect.Height + 1);
    }
    #endregion
}
```

Where drawing is done: (inside a PictureBox's Paint method, the PictureBox is called "DrawingRegion")

```
    //Rendering is done here because
    //the Graphics object is here.
    private void DrawingRegion_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
        e.Graphics.CompositingMode = CompositingMode.SourceCopy;
        e.Graphics.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.HighQuality;
        e.Graphics.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
        lock (game.Particles)
        {
            //Looping backwards because the collection can be
            //modified and that throws an exception.
            for (int i = game.Particles.Count - 1; i > 0; i--)
            {
                game.Particles[i].RenderFilledCircle(e.Graphics);
                game.Particles[i].RenderCircleBorder(e.Graphics);
            }
        }
    }
```

My game-loop:

```
    //The game process
    //which updates the particles' location
    //and checks whether or not it should start changing colors
    private void GameProc()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            lock (game.Particles)
            {
                //Looping backwards because the collection can be
                //modified and that throws an exception.
                for (int i = game.Particles.Count - 1; i > 0; i--)
                {
                    game.Particles[i].PerformFrame();
                }
            }
            Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() =>
            {
                DrawingRegion.Invalidate();
                DrawingRegion.Update();
            }));
        }
    }
```

If you think any other chunk of code is relevant, ask me to post it and I will.

Comment: Where do you call the drawing methods in Particle.cs?

Comment: It's called in the PictureBox's Paint method.
@AlexandreVaillancourt Why would I do that when it relates to the same application? People can answer which ever question they know the  answer to! =)

Comment: It doesn't seem like you call `OrderParticlesByZ()` anywhere

Comment: @ChrisUC I tried using it, and it didn't work. So I excluded it from the code because it didn't change the result.

Comment: I would highly recommend scrapping this completely and learning some simple OpenGL. If you're using C# look into OpenTK, which comes with a nifty OpenGL control.

Comment: @Krythic or Monogame.

Comment: Thank you I'll look into both of your guys' suggestions.

Comment: @Felsir Let's not muddy the programming water too much.

Comment: Just to clarify my reasoning. OpenGL has actual depth buffers. The order of your rendering won't matter(exceptions do exist for semi-transparent objects). Learning OpenGL(or Monogame which is DirectX) will also open the door for more extreme games down the road. It's difficult at first, but once you learn it I promise you will never look back.

Comment: Unfamiliar with the framework but wouldn't sorting the order of drawing by Z fix the problem? I think a simple insertionsort on the drawlist would be sufficient and fast enough. Depending on Moeyy's end-goal using openGL of directX might be overkill.

Comment: @user2645227 Unless two objects have the same Z. Then the one drawn first will overlap.

Comment: To expand user2645227 suggestion - what if you replace the game loop for cycle with something like `foreach(var p in game.Particles.OrderByDescending(p=>p.Location.Z)) p.PerformFrame();` ? Does that solve your problem?

Comment: @user2645227 I tried that and it did NOT work unfortunately, and what Krythic said is probably true.
wondra: that piece of code (the LINQ part) was in a function I had, which I tried, and did not work. And yes I'm sure the ordering worked because I debugged the problem. I tried OrderByDescending AND OrderBy.
I think my only option is to switch to OpenGL (I prefer it over Monogame as OpenGL is used in more than just C#, and I'm more interested in it anyways.)

Comment: @Moeyy, in which loop did you order the elements? In the GameProch for loop or the DrawingRegion_Paint loop? Since you are not changing the Z value in this code, performancewise i think it'd be more efficient to order the elements on insertion rather than in either loop but that should be irrelevant to the solution.

Comment: As for similar values, the same Z value in openGL will produce unwanted behaviour as well. Thats some handling you should do yourself. What do you want to happen when 2 objects use the same space (X, Y and Z)?

Comment: This kind of scene should be easily renderable by the painter algorithm, the complexity of 3D is not needed here. As other commentors have noted, the ordering is not present in the code, at leas I missed It. Add It in the proper place and your particles will render in the correct order. If I get to test it myself I will post as answer. I don't see where the particles are inserted into the list, but that method is the perfect place to do the ordering. As already noted, an insertion sort algorithm is the most optimal for this case as list is expected to be already ordered.

Comment: @user2645227 I order the list on insertion, not in the game loop. There is no reason for me to order it in the game loop, where no changes are made to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason, ordering the list works NOW.

Solution to this weird problem: ordering the list (on insertion, not in the game loop that would be a waste) by the list members' Z value like this: NameOfList = NameOfList.OrderBy(P => P.Location.Z).ToList();

All the comments were right, I was just so sure I tried it and it didn't work! proof that I tried it is that I had already written this method in my class, sorry for the misinformation on my part!